# How to code in excel macro to extract data to a new sheet as rows of data (new format)

Tags: excel, vba

In the attached [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNWXi.jpg), this report will be extracted to a new sheet as rows of data for input to ms access database. Sample output data shown on the lower part. Anyone has any idea on how to do it in excel macro? Thanks!

Comment: could you please upload a photo showing clearly rows & columns name?

Comment: sir Error 1004, are you referring to the output data? if yes, the following are the columns: report_date, subcon, equipment, area, qty and remarks. Report date can be extract from a specific cell in the report to be included in the output data.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to add additional information *in* the question, itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Dear @ROMEO SANDOVAL i try to create a code for you in order to provide some guidelines. See sheet structure & output and modify code to satisfy your needs.

Structure & Output:

[image]

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowFirst As Long, LastRowNext As Long, LastColumn As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Subcon As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

          LastRowFirst = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

          'Loop start from row 3 (Row after Description) up to the last row of column A
          For i = 3 To LastRowFirst
            'If range is not empty
            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
                If .Range("A" & i).Value = "CSTS" Or .Range("A" & i).Value = "MAMMOET" Or .Range("A" & i).Value = "GTA" Then
                    Subcon = .Range("A" & i).Value
                Else
                    'Loop start from column 3 (where the different spot appears) up to column 5
                    For j = 3 To 4
                        LastRowNext = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
                        .Cells(LastRowNext + 1, 6).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                        .Cells(LastRowNext + 1, 7).Value = Subcon
                        .Cells(LastRowNext + 1, 8).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                        .Cells(LastRowNext + 1, 9).Value = .Cells(2, j).Value
                        .Cells(LastRowNext + 1, 10).Value = .Cells(i, j).Value
                    Next j
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```